# Convert dictionary array into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am working with a dataset that is gridded, with time, latitude and longitude as indices, and monthly temperature as the actual variable. I first load in the data and extract the variable I want.

```
data=xr.open_dataset('E:/Riskpulse_HD/Jon climate study/adaptor.mars.internal-1583855532.1432714-8122-5-ace27afd-90c0-4a7d-b9ca-f3d5528c5ea1.nc')
temp = data['t2m'][:,0,:,:]-273
```

I create arrays with the values at the specific points. There is one value for each month starting at `1990-01-01`, then `1991-02-01` and so forth to present. Now I create a dictionary of several cities across the world at various lat,lon points.

```
Shanghai=temp.sel(latitude=31.25, longitude=121.5)
Singapore= temp.sel(latitude=1.25, longitude=103.75)
Shenzhen= temp.sel(latitude=22.5, longitude=114)
Ningbo_Zhoushan= temp.sel(latitude=29.75, longitude=121.5)
Guangzhou= temp.sel(latitude=23.0, longitude=113.5)

citiesdf = {
    "Shanghai": Shanghai,
    "Singapore": Singapore,
    "Shenzhen": Shenzhen,
    "Ningbo-Zhoushan": Ningbo_Zhoushan,
    "Guangzhou": Guangzhou}
```

Now I try and create the dataframe itself.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([citiesdf], columns=citiesdf.keys())
```

But I get some weird output that looks like this (just the first two cities).

```
    Shanghai                                                Singapore                            
0   [<xarray.DataArray 't2m' ()>\narray(5.1273193,...       [<xarray.DataArray 't2m' ()>\narray(26.064209,...
```

Ideally, I would like the time (each month) to be a row or index and have all of the temperature values unpack corresponding to the correct month. How would I arrive at this?

Comment: looks like you need to go from `xarray` to `pandas`; maybe [this](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/pandas.html) is helpful

Comment: Seems that doesn't have a good solution for dictionaries.